# Drupal 7 - How to transfer webform's data to a content type?

Tags: drupal-7, content-type, transfer, drupal-webform

First sorry for my English, I'll try to be clear!

I would like to transfer a webform's data to a content type after the submission. Does a module exist to do this, or will I have to use a hook?

Answer (score 0):

Case 1: one transfer new webform

1. you can use `hook_form_submit()` to directly get submitted data of all forms and choose your form with formId
2. Or use `hook_form_alter()` to add additional submit functions to the webfrom and then create a content using entity_create or node on form submit.

Case 2: use the Rules module for this purpose

If it's a migration of previous webforms then the solution is different.